# VB to C# conversion (Adding two bytes)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert a piece of Visual Basic code into c# but am having a problem adding the two byte arrays. The Visual Basic code is as follows:

```
 Private Function AndW(ByRef pBytWord1Ary, ByRef pBytWord2Ary)
    Dim lBytWordAry(3)
    Dim lLngIndex
    For lLngIndex = 0 To 3
        lBytWordAry(lLngIndex) = CByte(pBytWord1Ary(lLngIndex) And pBytWord2Ary(lLngIndex))
    Next
    AndW = lBytWordAry
End Function
```

My C# code:

```
private byte[] AndW(byte[] word1, byte[] word2)
    {
        byte[] newWord = new byte[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            newWord(i) = (word1(i) && word2(i));
        }
        return newWord;
    }
```

The code block inside my for loop isn't working and tells me method, event or delegate missing, any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You're likely to see an IndexOutOfRangeException - in an array declaration, the number in C# indicates the number of elements in the array (so you have indices 0, 1, and 2), where in VB it indicates the upper bound of the array (so you have indices 0, 1, 2, and 3). You should use `byte[] newWord = new byte[4];` and run your `for` loop `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` to have the same output as the VB code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need proper indexing:

```
newWord[i] = (byte)(word1[i] & word2[i]);
```

Also make sure to convert result to `byte`, since bitwise and for bytes returns integer in C#.

Comment: Thank you. I've had to cast it as well but its working now. Thanks